# Is it fine to customize C++?

Tags: c++

For my projects, I usually define a lot of aliases for types like unsigned int, char and double as well as std::string and others.

I also aliased and to &&, or to ||, not to !, etc.

- Is this considered bad practice or okay to do?

Comment: If you want other developers who join your projects to have a prayer of being productive, no.

Comment: Have you aliased `begin` to `{`, `end` or `fin` to `}`, and `ever` to `(;;)` or `(true)` yet?

Comment: I of course only did that for the operators because I believe the "natural" ones read better. All of the examples you mentioned would of course be bad.

Comment: @Frustrated: Hmm, I like that! `for ever { }` I'm going to use that in my next project :D

Comment: @Le: If you want `and`, `or`, etc., you might want to use something like Perl or VB instead, where those operators are part of the language.

Comment: @cdhowie: `and`, `or`, `not`, etc. _are_ part of C++.

Comment: @Le syntax: What do you mean by "alias and to &&"? `and` is an alternative token for `&&` so you can't `#define` it.

Comment: To generalize the answers: Mindless screwing around with the preprocessor, especially for 1:1 syntax changes "for convenience", is a deadly sin.

Comment: `and` and `or` are already among the 'alternative tokens` supported by C++ so you don't need to do this yourself.  Though to get them supported in MSVC++ you may need to use the `/Za` option (which often brings a lot of its own problems) or include `iso646.h`.  However, I'd agree with most comments that using the symbolic operators is more readable and preferable for most programmers.

Comment: @Charles: I cannot find any documentation to that effect. Also, you can `#define` pretty much anything -- those directives are handled by the preprocessor.

Comment: @Le syntax: as you guessed by now, the consensus is "no". C++ syntax is complex as it is. Fiddling with it usually only makes matters worse. The fact that everybody gets so heated up is they probably had to clean up after somebody who had some other "great idea"....

Comment: if "&&" is "and", what is YOUR token for "&".  Do you know the difference between "&&" and "&". Maybe "land" and "band" (logical-and and bitwise-and)???  or you could #undef and #define and to & when you need it to be a bit-wise-and, then #undef it and change it back to && when you need it to be logical-and.  ;-)

Comment: @cdhowie: Section 2.5 [lex.digraph] of C++03: `and` is `&&`, `bitor` is `|`, `or` is `||`, `xor` is `^`, `compl` is `~`, `bitand` is `&`, `and_eq` is `&=`, `or_eq` is `|=`, `xor_eq` is `^=`, `not` is `!`, `not_eq` is `!=`, `<%` is `{`, `%>` is `}`, `<:` is `[`, `:>` is `]`, `%:` is `#` and `%:%:` is `##`.

Comment: ..and then there's the genius who typedef'd true to 0 and false to 1 - true story

Comment: @Michael: granted that the symbolic operators are preferred by most C++ programmers. But “more readable”? You got to be f*ing kidding me. Apparently, C destroys your soul.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: As for readability, I have no data to support that argument either way. Maybe "easily recognized as familiar" or "easier to pick out amongst alphabetic variable names" would be a better phrase?

Comment: Personally I think you should always take care to mismatch digraph and trigraphs, e.g. `int main(int argc,char*argv??(:>)<%return 0;??>` Don't waste any characters on unnecessary whitespace.

Comment: @Konrad - maybe "readable" is not quite the right term, but it's the closest I can think of ("idiomatic" doesn't seem right for what I mean, either). Note that it's a contextual thing and applies only to practitioners - I wouldn't say the `&&` and `||` operators are more readable to non-C-style-language programmers. Kind of like how mathematical notation is quite expressive and readable to practitioners, but often quite alien to others (what the Hell do all those Greek letters mean?). The fact that Java and C# language designers kept the notation in those languages must say something?

Answer (score 22):

Defining types to add context within your code is acceptable, and even encouraged. Screwing around with operators will only encourage the next person that has to maintain your code to bring a gun to your house.

Comment: Reminds me the following quote: "Always code as if the person who will maintain your code is a maniac serial killer that knows where you live" :)

Comment: Google search + google maps + street view. Heck, even a robot could follow a trail like that.

Comment: @Tim Williscroft: Sounds like an action movie plot: the robot could be sent from the future to exterminate the person who's a threat to the sentient computers-- oh snap!

Answer (score 11):

Well, consider the newcomers who are accustomed to C++. They will have difficulties maintaining your project.

Mind that there are many possibilities for the more valid aliasing. A good example is complicated nested STL containers.

Example:

```
typedef int ClientID;
typedef double Price;
typedef map<ClientID, map<Date, Price> > ClientPurchases;
```

Now, instead of

```
map<int, map<Date, double> >::iterator it = clientPurchases.find(clientId);
```

you can write

```
ClientPurchases::iterator it = clientPurchases.find(clientId);
```

which seems to be more clear and readable.

Answer (score 10):

If you're only using it for *pointlessly* renaming language features (as opposed to the example @Vlad gives), then it's the [Wrong Thing](http://catb.org/jargon/html/W/Wrong-Thing.html).

It definitely makes the code less readable - anyone proficient in C++ will see `(x ? y : z)` and know that it's a ternary [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1%28VS.71%29.aspx). Although `ORLY x YARLY y NOWAI z KTHX` *could be* the same thing, it will confuse the viewer: "is this `YARLY NOWAI` the exact same thing as `? :`, renamed for the author's convenience, or does it have subtle differences?" If these "aliases" are the same thing as the standard language elements, they will only slow down the next person to maintain your code.

TLDR: Reading code, any code, is hard enough without having to look up your private alternate syntax all the time.

Comment: people *really* proficient will know `and` is already a keyword :D

Comment: @Ciscol: nitpick: it’s actually a preprocessing token (which resolves to `&&`), not a keyword. ;-)

Comment: @CiscoIPPhone: yup. Changed to a sillier example - I sincerely hope *those* aren't real keywords ;)

Answer (score 5):

That’s horrible. Don’t do it, please. Write idiomatic C++, not some macro-riddled monstrosity. In general, it’s **extremely** bad practice to define such macros, except in very specific cases (such as the `BOOST_FOREACH` macro).

That said, `and`, `or` and `not` are actually *already* valid aliases for `&&`, `||` and `!` in C++!

It’s just that Visual Studio only knows them if you first include the standard header `<ciso646>`. Other compilers don’t need this.

Types are something else. Using `typedef` to create type aliases depending on context makes sense if it augments the expressiveness of the code. Then it’s encouraged. However, even better would be to create *own types* instead of aliases. For example, I can’t imagine it ever being beneficial to create an alias for `std::string` – why not just use `std::string` directly? (An exception are of course generic data structures and algorithms.)

Answer (score 4):

- "and", "or", "not" are OK because they're part of the language, but it's probably better to write C++ in a style that other C++ programmers use, and very few people bother using them. Don't alias them yourself: they're reserved names and it's not valid in general to use reserved names even in the preprocessor. If your compiler doesn't provide them in its default mode (i.e. it's not standard-compliant), you *could* fake them up with `#define`, but you may be setting yourself up for trouble in future if you change compiler, or change compiler options.
- typedefs for builtin types might make sense in certain circumstances. For example in C99 (but not in C++03), there are extended integer types such as `int32_t`, which specifies a 32 bit integer, and on a particular system that might be a typedef for `int`. They come from `stdint.h` (`<cstdint>` in C++0x), and if your C++ compiler doesn't provide that as an extension, you can generally hunt down or write a version of it that will work for your system. If you have some purpose in mind for which you might in future want to use a different integer type (on a different system perhaps), then by all means hide the "real" type behind a name that describes the important properties that are the reason you chose that type for the purpose. If you just think "int" is unnecessarily brief, and it should be "integer", then you're not really helping anyone, even yourself, by trying to tweak the language in such a superficial way. It's an extra indirection for no gain, and in the long run you're better off learning C++, than changing C++ to "make more sense" to you.
- I can't think of a good reason to use any other name for `string`, except in a case similar to the extended integer types, where your name will perhaps be a typedef for `string` on some builds, and `wstring` on others.
- If you're not a native English-speaker, and are trying to "translate" C++ to another language, then I sort of see your point but I don't think it's a good idea. Even other speakers of your language will know C++ better than they know the translations you happen to have picked. But I am a native English speaker, so I don't really know how much difference it makes. Given how many C++ programmers there are in the world who *don't* translate languages, I suspect it's not a huge deal compared with the fact that all the documentation is in English...

Comment: Excel and Visual Basic tried translated keywords for a while, and it was terrible (Yes, even more terrible than VB and Excel are anyway)

Answer (score 0):

If every C++ developer was familiar with your aliases then why not, but you are with these aliases essentially introducing a new language to whoever needs to maintain your code.

Why add this extra mental step that for the most part does not add any clarity (&& and || are pretty obvious what they are doing for any C/C++ programmer, and any way in C++ you can use the `and` and `or` keywords)